# Sitecore 8.0 newrelic integration

Tags: integration

How should i start to integrate NewRelic with Sitecore CMS?
How does it works?

> I'm trying to use NewRelic with Sitecore CMS 8.

I'm Using Sitecore version 8.0 update 3.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with New Relic Sitecore module in the Sitecore market place

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/New_Relic.aspx

In the documentation tab you will find the installation instructions.

Comment: New_Relic module is working for 6.6, I don't think it will work with 8.0.3